# My code works till inserting second test code

Tags: python

I have further edited this code from below from my original.

```
ALPHA = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
def repr2dec(num, base):
    total = 0
    for ix, digit in enumerate(reversed(num)):
        total += ALPHA.index(digit) * base ** ix
    return total

print(repr2dec("23", 21) == 45)
print(repr2dec("11", 72) == 73)
print(repr2dec("43", 13) == 55)
print(repr2dec("AD", 15) == 163)
```

My current error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nt-test-6269e744", line 3, in <module>
    assert(convert.repToDecimal("23", 21) == 45)
AttributeError: module 'convert' has no attribute 'repToDecimal'
```

I believe I am heading in the right direction, but am unable to figure out my next step.

Comment: Your string `alpha` is 36 characters long, and you're trying to compute something in base 72. This line is failing: `val[alpha[i]] = i` because `i` can grow larger than 36.

Comment: How would I correct something like that? And does inserting the code in def main() as is correct?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.